# PNPDeviceID Format

Tags: wmi, device

I'm working on developing a WMI query for my application.  It needs to find the assigned virtual COM port for a given VID/PID.  Using the WMI Code Creator I have found that...

- Namespace: root\CIMV2
- Class: Win32_SerialPort
- Property: PNPDeviceID

...returns a value of `USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\0001`.  This same value can be found by going to the appropriate entry in Device Manager -> Properties -> Details tab and selecting Device Instance Id.

My question is, what does the `\0001` signify?  Or, can I expect my device to have a device ID of `USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\0001` when plugged into any Windows system?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It references the device instance.  That is, devices with identical identifiers (more than one plugged in) are enumerated, so that the system can identify them.

http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/959095-solved-pnpdeviceid-format.html#3

Comment: Does that mean that the PNPDeviceID is no unique ID to identify an USB flash drive for example?

Comment: @L4c0573 Correct, two USB flash drives will have identical first two parts of `PNPDeviceId` (`USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60`), while the last third part will depend on port/slot you inserted the drive (`0001`). You want to get serial number to identify a device. Try this PowerShell command: `gwmi Win32_DiskDrive | Format-Table PNPDeviceId,DeviceId,Model,SerialNumber`.